# Google Sheets: Query where date>now() returns nothing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Sheets query function to bring data from a different sheet. This query works perfectly, matching two text fields (Where A='"&A5&"')

```
=query('Modifications'!$A$3:$I,"Select E,F,G,H,I Where A='"&A5&"'order by E desc limit 1")
```

However, when I try to add an AND statement as part of the Where clause to filter by today's date ( now() ), the query returns nothing:

```
=query('Modifications'!$A$3:$I,"Select E,F,G,H,I Where A='"&A5&"' AND F>now() order by E desc limit 1")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY('Modifications'!$A$3:$I, 
 "select E,F,G,H,I 
  where A = '"&A5&"' 
    and F > date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
  order by E desc 
  limit 1", 0)
```

Comment: Didn't work. Probably because my dates are in the following format: 1/30/2019.

Comment: do you have a valid dates in F column? - https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/

Comment: You got it my friend. I was using Sept 31, 2019, a date that does not exist. Thank you.