# Filtering on google sheets using Query returns just one row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Context**

I am trying to filter data by date range using Query. I want data from 31/12/2019 onwards. This is the formula I used:

`=Query(Query(ImportRange("ID", "RotorkPrice"),"offset 2",1),"select * where Col1 >= '2019-12-31'")`

This only returns the top row (though I did ask Query to remove the first 2 rows). The data looks like so:

[image]

I took examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815530/google-sheets-query-where-datenow-returns-nothing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729522/using-query-import-range-and-named-range-to-either-label-the-named-range-or-ign), and have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFZnSY0YdwU) guide.

**Problem**

Is there a way to only draw data from this date onwards using Query?

The spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FyQmHwnNSMfZ-zb7yXDMH4ARe0fnfAROvf3ZKBB0XZo/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, free of sensitive information?

Comment: @lamblichus thank you for responding. Have attached the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `date`. try:

```
=QUERT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "RotorkPrice"), 
 "offset 1", 0), 
 "where Col1 >= date '2019-12-31'", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works but its still returning the wrong headers. I want it to return the 'Date and Close' but it returns the first row, not the 3rd

Comment: Thanks this removed the first row. It did not produce the third row but I can just write those myself. Much appreciated :)