# Using Query to get the dates from a cell Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Context**

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785169/filtering-on-google-sheets-using-query-returns-just-one-row) question, I am trying to make this more dynamic. I want to input data in a cell 'D1' to then make Query bring back the data from another spreadsheet. Below is a depiction of what this looks like.

[image]

This is the formula I tried:
`=QUERY(Query(ImportRange("ID", "AvevaGroupPrice"),"offset 1", 0), "where Col1 >= Date " &D1)`
I used this format because eventually I want to create a dynamic date range where I type the respective dates I need in the first two 'D' rows.

**Problem**

How can I make this work using data in cell D1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Query Language Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals), when you include `date` keyword you need to use a date with `yyyy-mm-dd` format

In your current function, the date was converted to a number when appended to the string.

**Sample:** `="date "&D1`

**Result: date 43830**

You need to use [TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) to convert the date to yyyy-mm-dd format.

**Sample:** `="where Col1 >= Date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"`

**Result: where Col1 >= Date '2019-12-31'**

---

**(UPDATE)**

You can also use [TO_TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285) to convert the Cell Value to a text value.

**Sample:** `="where Col1 >= Date '"&To_text(D1)&"'"`

**Result: where Col1 >= Date '2019-12-31'**

---

### Your Formula:

`=QUERY(Query(ImportRange("ID", "AvevaGroupPrice"),"offset 1", 0), "where Col1 >= Date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")`

or

`=QUERY(Query(ImportRange("ID", "AvevaGroupPrice"),"offset 1", 0), "where Col1 >= Date '"&To_text(D1)&"'")`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Was trying to avoid the long formula but if it can't then not much to do. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, i updated my answer. I didn't know you are looking for a shorter way. You can use [TO_TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094285) to convert your date to a text value directly.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! :)