# Trying to input data from a cell in google sheets QUERY but its not working

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reference a cell in google sheets, but it never works, unless I type it in like in the example below. I don't want to have to type in every Date number.... I have no idea why its not reading C3 correctly, when it works if I just type the number in (43770)... Please help, driving me nuts

```
=QUERY('Little Hotellier Report Output'!2:4960, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE H<='"&C3&"' AND H>=43770 AND NOT A = '' GROUP BY A LABEL COUNT(A) ''", 0)
```

Been googling and every result I find doing the '"&&C3&&'" seems to work....

Comment: See [Filtering With Dates In The QUERY Function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Query to get the dates from a cell Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794049/using-query-to-get-the-dates-from-a-cell-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

here is your code

```
=QUERY('Little Hotellier Report Output'!2:4960, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE H<='"&C3&"' AND H>=43770 AND NOT A = '' GROUP BY A LABEL COUNT(A) ''", 0)
```

and I don't know if I understood you correctly, but try my suggestions and let me know if it helped

first try - I added cell C3 here, remember that the formatting of cell C3 must be appropriate for Query to work properly

```
=QUERY('Little Hotellier Report Output'!2:4960, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE H<='"&C3&"' AND H>= DATE '"&TEXT(C3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND NOT A = '' GROUP BY A LABEL COUNT(A) ''", 0)
```